# Traveling with 2 passorts

Tags: passports

I have a UK passport and a Malaysian passport and am traveling to the US, I want to use my UK passport because it has a visa waiver, but to return home (Australia) I want to use my Malaysian passport because it has my citizenship in it. Can I do this?

Comment: Presumably _each_ of your passports has one of your citizenships in it??